# Gradle 1.7 with Java 1.8: compileGroovy error?

Tags: java, groovy, gradle, java-8

When I try to build my java project using Java `1.8` and Gradle `1.7` I am getting the following error:

```
  Execution failed for task ':compileGroovy'.
> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit 'C:\...\groovy\org\gradle\plugins\svnkit\GroovySvnKitPluginConve
ntion.groovy' 

Could not load class 'org.gradle.plugins.svnkit.svnclient.WorkingC
opy' from file:/C:/.../gradle/p
lugins/svnkit/svnclient/WorkingCopy.class.
```

My project builds in Java 7, what could be the issue now with Java 8?

Comment: I am using Groovy version 1.8, I need to update this?

Comment: If you can, I'd say it's generally a good idea to keep Gradle and Groovy current... 1.8 is pretty old. Also, do you actually have Java 8 installed on the machine?

Comment: Yes Java 8 is installed, do i need a newer version of gradle to use it?

Comment: I added some extra info in error message, thanks

Comment: Post an example build script that fails, we're getting no-where with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of Groovy are you compiling with (in your dependencies)?

Groovy doesn't support Java 8 until 2.3.

If that doesn't fix it, and it is a more internal Gradle issue (it's hard to tell as you don't post and example build script, or the full exception), you might need to upgrade to Gradle 2+ as that is when they migrated to the Java 8 supporting versions of Groovy.

Comment: I am using Groovy version 1.8, I need to update this?

Comment: I believe so if you want to use it with Java 8

Comment: What version of Gradle is compatible with Java 8? thanks for your help

Comment: In your build script, which version of Groovy do you have in your dependencies?  Have you tried upgrading it?  I assume this is a groovy application, as otherwise `compileGroovy` wouldn't be running?

Comment: I get the feeling you're getting the wrong end of the stick?

Comment: Im building the proect with gradle, is there a specific version that I need to support Java 8?

Comment: in my buildscript dependenices i have groovy 2.4.5 ?

Comment: Post your full `build.gradle`